# How to close SQLite database connection when using Python and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook to query an SQLite database running on a Raspberry Pi. I'm a beginner and I'm trying to learn to write 'good' Python and [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561832/what-if-i-dont-close-the-database-connection-in-python-sqlite) say I should close the database connection after I have finished with it. I had been using

```
if conn:
    conn.close()
```

but this morning I decided to try experimenting with `with` so to check it was working I added `print(conn)`. This returned `<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x6d13####>`. More searching showed that `with` will commit but not close SQLite connections, so I added

```
with closing(sqlite3.connect(db_file)) as conn:
```

which according to that same link should fix it. But print still returned an object. I then tried adding the print test on my original if and .close() method but that still returned an object. Is there something wrong with both my close methods, or am I misunderstanding what `print(conn)` is telling me, or is there something about Jupyter that is stopping either method from closing the connection? [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895053/how-to-close-a-connection-when-using-jupyter-sql-magic) suggests that Jupyter might be the problem? If it is Jupyter, how should I close the connection or do I just stop worrying about it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use two different sqlite databases in Jupyter. The problem was that even if I started the second connection with a different name, the program was still using the first one.

I solved the problem by assigning None to the connection

```
conn.close()
conn = None
```

and only then I was able to connect to the second database.

I know that it doesn't makes sense, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be fine, `print(conn)` will always return a `<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x######>`, even after `conn.close()` is called.